# Is it possible Android preferences broken?

Tags: android, preferences

I am testing an app with Samsung Galaxy 2. I am facing a very strange error. I got an NullpointerException or unknown error not displayed in LogCat when I read preferences. My code read the preferences here:

```
public class PrefsUtil {

  private static SharedPreferences getPrefs(Context context) {
        return context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
   }

   public static String getString(Context context, String key, String defValue){
    return getPrefs(context).getString(key, defValue); 
   }

//...more

}

public class DeviceSetting {
    public String deviceId;
}

public class Setting {
    public static DeviceSetting options;

    public static void loadSettings(Context context){
         options.deviceId = PrefsUtil.getString(context, R.string.deviceId, "");
         //...
    }
}
```

When I call loadSetting, error happens.

```
Setting.loadSettings(context);
```

I found that PrefsUtil.getString() causes error through debugging. I can't find the cause. The context is not null. Please let me know what is wrong?

Comment: Please post your LogCat output showing the error.

Comment: Can it be you're passing null as a context?

Comment: I found the reason. The variable options was not created. Unintentionally, the code assigns the object to variable removed.